# Use a proxy during a docker build

Tags: docker

I am under Linux and I have a problem when I want to do a docker build.
I followed the instructions of the docker website to add a proxy https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

I have no problem when I do a docker run or a docker compose the images download without problem.

However, as soon as I do a docker build or a docker compose which contains a build, I get this kind of error for example :

> ### Dockerfile:1
>
> ### 1 | >>> FROM scenari/jetty:6.1
> 2 | USER root
> 3 | COPY root.cer DCI_CA_root.cer
>
> ERROR: failed to solve: DeadlineExceeded: DeadlineExceeded: failed to fetch anonymous token: Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Ascenari%2Fjetty%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": dial tcp 34.205.13.154:443: i/o timeout

Apparently it does not support my proxy configuration.

I use Docker Docker version 23.0.1, build a5ee5b1
Do you have a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We have noticed the same problem after the latest OS and docker upgrade to 23.0.1, build a5ee5b1

```
[user@host test]# docker build .
[+] Building 31.2s (4/4) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.7s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 61B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.6s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:11                                                                                                                                                                                         30.5s
 => [auth] library/eclipse-temurin:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:11:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM eclipse-temurin:11
   2 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: DeadlineExceeded: DeadlineExceeded: failed to fetch oauth token: Post "https://auth.docker.io/token": dial tcp 3.216.34.172:443: i/o timeout
```

In the past we've configured our proxy for docker in the `~/config.json` file and in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`

With only this configuration in place we were able to succesfully execute `docker pull eclipse-temurin:11` but I was not able to do `docker build .` with a Dockerfile that contained `FROM eclipse-temurin:11`

Since the latest update those configurations are not taken into account and we had to set the environment variables `http_proxy`and `https_proxy` directly in the shell. Afterwards it just worked perfectly fine. I've put this configuration into a shell script in `/etc/profile.d/http_proxy.sh` so its loaded by default.

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.1.2:3128
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://192.168.1.2:3128
export NO_PROXY=localhost,*.company.com
```

I think this goes back to a change in Docker/Buildkit